# two different reputations in graph and history

Tags: bug, reputation, reputation-history, reputation-graph

I see two different reputations in reputation graph and history:

[image]

The difference is exactly 100 and is probably due to a +100 from "trust on other sites in the network"

Comment: Reputation gets only updated after some time.